# Matching multiple relationships in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to form a query that matches against multiple relationships. Here is my query torn down to the basics:

```
START inputMovie=node(1)
MATCH inputMovie<-[r:RATED]-User-[o:RATED]->(movies)<-[:IS_GENRE]->genres
RETURN movies.title LIMIT 5
```

I want it to return a list of movies that have been rated the same person, and are of the same genre. What am I doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, as Cypher does not allow bidirectional relationships: `<-[:IS_GENRE]->`.

Taking a guess at your data model, this might work for you:

```
START inputMovie=node(1)
MATCH inputMovie<-[r:RATED]-User-[o:RATED]->(movies)-[:IS_GENRE]->genres
RETURN movies.title LIMIT 5;
```

Note: the above query can return duplicate results, since multiple users can watch the same movies. If this is a concern, you can use the `DISTINCT` qualifier to prevent that. For example:

```
START inputMovie=node(1)
MATCH inputMovie<-[r:RATED]-User-[o:RATED]->(movies)-[:IS_GENRE]->genres
RETURN DISTINCT movies.title LIMIT 5;
```

[EDITED]

If you want to return only movies that have (at least) all of the same genres as the `inputMovie`, you can do the following.

```
START inputMovie=node(1)
MATCH (inputGenre)<-[:IS_GENRE]-(inputMovie)
WITH inputMovie, COLLECT(inputGenre) AS inputGenres
MATCH (inputMovie)<-[r:RATED]-(User)-[o:RATED]->(movie)-[:IS_GENRE]->(genre)
WITH inputGenres, movie, COLLECT(genre) AS genres
WHERE ALL(x IN inputGenres WHERE x IN genres)
RETURN movie.title LIMIT 5;
```

Notes:

- I have renamed a couple of identifiers, for clarity (i.e., `movies` and `genres`).
- The `DISTINCT` qualifier is no longer needed, as aggregation over the `movie` node (in the second `WITH` clause) implicitly makes each `movie` instance unique.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was my typo. Although now I've got the query working, I'm getting odd results, for example The Sixth Sense will match with Up (pixar) because they both share the Drama genre. Do you know of a way to match with ALL genres, rather than just one?

Comment: Are you trying to get movies that have (at least) all of the same genres as the `inputMovie`?

Comment: yeah I am. some movies have been classed as more than one genre.

Comment: nice, it works! I'm going to read through the relevant documentation for these commands so I know how it works now :)